# sql syntax error count

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

i have this query to calculate the stock

```
SELECT (receipt_count - COALESCE(sales_count, 0)) AS 'stock'
FROM (
SELECT SUM(spares_receipt.aantal_ontvangen) AS 'receipt_count'
FROM spares_receipt WHERE Number = 1001000 
) AS 'Receipt'
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT SUM(spares_sales.aantal_verkocht) AS 'sales_count'
FROM spares_sales WHERE onderdeel_nummer = 1001000
) AS 'Sales'
```

but i get this error:

```
SELECT (receipt_count - COALESCE(sales_count, 0)) AS 'stock'
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(spares_receipt.aantal_ontvangen) AS 'receipt_count'
    FROM spares_receipt WHERE Number = 1001000 
) AS 'Receipt'
LEFT JOIN
 (
    SELECT SUM(spares_sales.aantal_verkocht) AS 'sales_count'
    FROM spares_sales WHERE onderdeel_nummer = 1001000
) AS 'Sales'
 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL meldt: Documentatie

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Receipt'
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(spares_sales.aantal_verkocht) AS 'sales_co' at line 5
```

But what is the fault in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Aliases need to be in ticks, not single quotes:

```
SELECT (receipt_count - COALESCE(sales_count, 0)) AS `stock`
FROM (
SELECT SUM(spares_receipt.aantal_ontvangen) AS `receipt_count`
FROM spares_receipt WHERE Number = 1001000 
) AS `Receipt`
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT SUM(spares_sales.aantal_verkocht) AS `sales_count`
FROM spares_sales WHERE onderdeel_nummer = 1001000
) AS `Sales`
```

Optionally, you may omit the ticks altogether and use nothing at all.

Comment: Just a note - in the select list of a query, you can use single quotes.  Anywhere else, though, you have to use identifier quoting or it's treated as a string rather than as a reference.  This is why the error happened on `Receipt` and not on `stock` or `receipt_count`

Comment: with your code i get this error: SELECT (receipt_count - COALESCE(sales_count, 0)) AS `stock`
FROM (
SELECT SUM(spares_receipt.aantal_ontvangen) AS `receipt_count`
FROM spares_receipt WHERE Number = 1001000 
) AS `Receipt`
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT SUM(spares_sales.aantal_verkocht) AS `sales_count`
FROM spares_sales WHERE onderdeel_nummer = 1001000
) AS `Sales`
 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL meldt: Documentatie

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 11